# Underlying reason for similarities between summation inverse and differentiation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So let's say I have the series where $n$ is an integer variable:

$$S_a = \sum_{r=1}^n a_r$$

$$S_b = \sum_{r=1}^n b_r$$

We define summation inverse as a mapping such that:

$$ \sum_n^{-1} S_a = a_r$$

One can easily prove (where $c$ is a constant):
$$ \sum^{-1} c S_a = c \sum^{-1} S_a = c a_r$$
$$ \sum^{-1} S_a + S_b = a_r + b_r$$
$$ \sum^{-1}(S_a S_b) = a_r S_b + b_r S_a$$

On the other hand I see alot of similarities between:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = f'(x)$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx} c f(x) = c \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = c f'(x)$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx} f(x) + g(x) = f'(x) + g'(x)$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx} (f(x) g(x)) = f'(x) g(x) + f(x) g'(x)$$

### Question

Is there any fundamental reason as to why?

Comment: I don't specifically know of a good modern reference for this, but I frequently encounter this topic in my various perusals of 1800s mathematics literature. See, for example, [this 1845 book by Thomas Tate](https://archive.org/details/atreatiseonfact00tategoog) and [this 1880 book by George Boole](https://archive.org/details/cu31924031240934/page/n5/mode/2up). This [google books search for finite+difference+calculus, restricted to the 19th century](https://www.google.com/search?q=finite+difference+calculus&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899), will lead you to many other such books.

Comment: Your "summation inverse" is usually called a difference operator.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#difference_operator).  The basic reason "why" is that the derivative is a limit of scaled differences.

Comment: Your rules don't make sense because you haven't defined the things you're applying the "summation inverse" to as sums. If you replace them with first differences f(x)-f(x-1), then the "product rule" is wrong. f(x)g(x)=f(x)(g(x)-g(x-1))+f(x)g(x-1)=f(x)(g(x)-g(x-1))+(f(x)-f(x-1))g(x-1)+f(x-1)g(x-1), so subtracting f(x-1)g(x-1) we have f(x)(g(x)-g(x-1))+(f(x)-f(x-1))g(x-1), or by symmetry f(x-1)(g(x)-g(x-1))+g(x)(f(x)-f(x-1)). NOT f(x)(g(x)-g(x-1))+g(x)(f(x)-f(x-1)), which is what I presume you meant.